# How can I iterate over image resources inside one group?

Tags: iphone, uikit

In my "Groups & Files" I have created something like that:

images > gui
images > foo
images > foo > bar

now I want to iterate over all images that are placed in images > foo > bar. Is that possible? I am afraid it's not, because the system did never care much about "folders" when loading a file.

Answer (score 2):

If your images are in a sub-folder of your .app bundle, you can create an nsbundle for that folder and call pathsForResourcesOfType to get an nsareay of the paths.

Comment: How would I create that NSBundle?

Comment: [NSBundle bundleWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@""]